# Are there any non-Apple Thunderbolt displays?

Tags: display, thunderbolt

Are there any Thunderbolt displays produced by anyone besides Apple?

Apple charges about twice the price of equivalent monitors without the thunderbolt port.  Apple may handle the cable jungle better, but that'll never be worth the extra cost.

Comment: Hardware and shopping recommendation ("let's go shopping") questions are off topic here. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: sorry @jeff I agree with nathan, a simple Google search here will do the trick

Comment: I haven't found anything from google searches.  <shrug>

Comment: I'm kind of with Jeff on this one. It appears the answer is no, which, by the way, is not answered by a simple Google search, since finding nothing causes me to keep searching. I did find this however, and a "as of 2/27/12, no" answer would have been really helpful.